# Problems when editing. Exe file sc_serv.exe shoutcast

Tags: edit, shoutcast

I need to edit an executable file from shoutcast, sc_serv.exe. If I just open this file in notepad, and save again without editing anything, after trying to run the program I get the message:

```
Program too big to fit in memory
```

How do I open and save the executable without interfering with its operation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just blindly edit an EXE, especially not with Notepad.

If you're trying to edit the admin interface for SHOUTcast, the best thing to do is proxy its returned data through PHP, or something else server-side, to create your own interface.  I've done this, and found it to be fairly straight forward.